# How do you disable the rolling refresh animation in the WPF ToolKit DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit, xceed

I have screen which shows data in a `DataGrid` through the `DataGridCollectionView` from an `Observable` collection.  The ViewModels polls the data every 50 seconds or so and Add/Update/Deletes items in the collection.  When this happens however there is this (attempting accurate description here) rolling refresh animation looking thing from the top down, almost row by row.

I'm sure this might look "cool" in some situations but the application has stricter guidelines on flicker, and frankly after the first few times its just annoying.  The problem is, try as I might, I can't seem to figure out how to turn it off or make it stop.  Searching and looking through documentation has not provided any clues.

Does anyone know how to disable the apparent "refresh animation" on the `Datagrid` when it updates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A rather smart colleague of mine found the answer.

The TableFlowView exposes 3 properties that seem to impact this behavior.

```
RowFadeInAnimationDuration="0"
ScrollingAnimationDuration="0"
IsDeferredLoadingEnabled="False"
```

As a bit of warning though, setting the last property will effectively disable the virtualization.  In our case however even with 1000's of rows and 40 columns we saw no degradation of performance.